# Publish Portable and Self-Contained .NET Application in Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, .net-5, portable-applications

I need to release an application that:

1. must not be installed
2. must not involve the installation of dependencies for its execution if they are not installed on the PC in use (no versions of C ++, versions of .net Framework, etc ...).

For this purpose I made the application in .NET 5.0 and published it according to the settings visible in the image.
In the settings I specify the Self-Contained property.
[image: Publish Configuration]

Running the application on Windows 11, Windows 10 and Windows 8.1 I have no problems but on Windows 7 I have a .NET Runtime ID 1023 error as in the image.
[image: Windows 7 Error]

What could be the problem? How should I publish the application so that I don't need to install anything?

Comment: Side note: getting an app build with an unsupported runtime on the unsupported OS may be tricky... Consider not spending your time on it... Check out https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/5.0/5.0-supported-os.md, https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core. If you really have to use vanilla Win7 - than Net 3.5 is your choice - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Windows 7 SP1 is supported only with *Extended Security Updates* installed. The same statement also applies to net6.

I managed to get it to work (with net6) by installing those updates from the Microsoft Update Catalog:

- Windows6.1-KB3063858-x64.msu
- Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu
- Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3191566-x64.zip

> this is Windows Management Framework 5.1

- Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64) - 14.29.30135

In addition, in some installation, I had to also install PowerShell v7.2.1 .

I was unable to run the application on a fresh install of Windows 7 SP1 in any way.