# Asp.net core 3.1 console app on windows 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

To explain it quickly, I just created an asp.net core 3.1 console app it works well on Windows 10, but it doesn't work on Windows 7 64/32 bit, at first I had some problem with hostfxr.dll that was missing manage to fix with using this line : "dotnet publish -r win-x64 --self-contained true -c release". But then i sill have to fix another problem, which is as below.

[image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: @BennySchärer the client doesn't want to install anything...

Comment: "the client doesn't want to install anything": `self-contained` does exactly this.

Comment: @nilsK well i did this command line "dotnet publish -r win-x64 --self-contained true -c release" but i still hae the runtime problem

Comment: @Azaphyr sorry, wasn't sure. Maybe its a compatibility issue mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72849510/publish-portable-and-self-contained-net-application-in-windows-7